# Convert a char array to a string and store the string?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, dev-c++

I want to use a string converted from a char array, but the string seems to change when I edit my char array. I realized that both are pointing to the same location in memory and tried to store the string in a new string. However, the new string still changes when I edit the char array even though they have different memory locations. How do I not change the new string when editing the original array? I'm using Dev C++ by the way.

```
char str[] = "Test test";
string z(str);
string s = z;
printf("%s, str[]'s location = %d, z location = %d, s location = %d", s, str, z, &s);
str[0] = 'n';
printf("\n%s, str[]'s location = %d, z location = %d, s location = %d", s, str, z, &s);
```

Comment: What compiler are you using ?

Comment: You're printing stuff incorrectly, your warnings should've told you that. Read the manual for `printf`, or even better just use `cout`.

Comment: Use cout, not printf. You are using it already wrong!

Comment: `%d` is used to print integer values, `std::string` cannot be resolved for formatting with `printf()`. Why are you using `printf()` for console out put in c++ at all? Use `std::cout` instead.

Comment: @TheDude Well, OP *could* use `.c_str()`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Sure, but then that's still not very _idiomatic_ c++ code.

Comment: what you have here is Undefined Behavior. Anything can happen, dont try to reason about the results. As others have said - fix the compiler warnings, - use cout

Comment: Hi there, I'm using Dev C++. Thank you all for the comments. However, there was no warning when I compiled my code and changing from printf to cout still doesn't fix the problem (the string still changes) :(

Answer (score 3):

> I want to use a string converted from a char array, but the string seems to change when I edit my char array.

The std::string is not modified in any way when you edit your char array.

> I realized that both are pointing to the same location

They don't point to the same location.

> and tried to store the string in a new string. However, the new string still changes when I edit the char array

The other std::string is not modified either.

> How do I not change the new string when editing the original array?

Just like you do in the example: `str[0] = 'n';`.

---

Your problem is that the program has undefined behaviour. `printf` has strict requirements to the type of arguments that are given. Your program does not satisfy those requirements:

```
"\n%s, str[]'s location = %d, z location = %d, s location = %d"
    ^                      ^                ^                ^
    |           %d requires that the argument is int. None of str, z, &s is int
    %s requires that the argument is char*. s is a std::string instead
```

It will be easier to use `std::cout` to show that the string does not change:

```
char str[] = "Test test";
string s(str);
std::cout << s << '\n'; // prints Test test
str[0] = 'n';
std::cout << s << '\n'; // prints Test test
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems like the problem was caused by my compiler (DEV C++) because when I cout the string, the first letter of the string was changed. :(